# Assigning default value if using unset or blank value?

Tags: variable-assignment, default-value

```
echo "Please enter the Clickhouse IP Address if its available otherwise Enter as blank:"
read db_ip

if [ $db_ip =' ' ]; 

then
      FOO=${db_ip:=default}

fi
```

Comment: Please edit your question add relevant technology tags.

Comment: Anybody please response on my query.
I need assistance for my shell scripting.